# How to convert audio file into byte array

Tags: java, arrays, file, audio

I want to convert an audio file into a byte array. I currently did it and I want to know if its works :

```
    private static AudioFormat getFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 44100;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
            bigEndian);
}

public static byte[] listenSound(File f) {

    AudioInputStream din = null;
    AudioInputStream outDin = null;
    PCM2PCMConversionProvider conversionProvider = new PCM2PCMConversionProvider();

    try {
        AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f);
        AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
        AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(
                    AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    16,
                    baseFormat.getChannels(),
                    baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    false);

        din = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

        if (!conversionProvider.isConversionSupported(getFormat(), decodedFormat)) {
            System.out.println("Conversion Not Supported.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        outDin = conversionProvider.getAudioInputStream(getFormat(), din);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int n = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            n++;
            if (n > 1000)
                break;

            int count = 0;
            count = outDin.read(buffer, 0, 1024);

            if (count > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
        }
        in.close();
        din.close();
        outDin.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        //byte[] b=out.toByteArray();
        //for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        //System.out.println("b = "+b[i]);
        return out.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That byte array data is actually known as time domain i need to be sure if it works before transforming this data into frequency domain with Discrete Fourier.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: In what format?  WAV?  MP3?  3GP?  FLAC?  MMF?  OGG?  RA?  WMA?  Some other format?

Comment: Are you talking about the files in entry? if yes it can be in format mp3 or wav

Answer (score 0):

typically the actual number of bytes processed is returned from a call like

```
count = outDin.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
```

so in addition to your current hard break after processing 1000 chunks if the API does in fact return a byte count you should check for it :

```
int size_chunk = 1024
byte[] buffer = new byte[size_chunk];
boolean keep_streaming = true;
while (keep_streaming) {
    n++;
    if (n > 1000) {  // troubleshooting ONLY remove later

        keep_streaming = false;
    }

    int count = 0;
    count = outDin.read(buffer, 0, size_chunk);

    if (count > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }

    if (count < size_chunk) {  //  input stream has been consumed
        keep_streaming = false;
    }
}
```

You did not supply a link to the API doc so I cannot confirm, however assuming  outDin.read will output the number of bytes actually processed, the above code will correctly output only the bytes to match input and so will result in a smaller output if input is less than 1 meg of data (your original logic blindly generated a 1 meg output stopped only after seeing 1000 chunks ... it also assumes you intend to truncate input after 1 meg of data as per your lines

```
    if (n > 1000) {  // troubleshooting ONLY remove later

        keep_streaming = false;
    }
```